# Disable CAPTCHA for logins

Tags: authentication, captcha, confluence

We upgraded Confluence to v3.5.17 and we reset the admin password but it is asking for login confirmation with a CAPTCHA that doesn't work.

How we can disable the CAPTCHA login in the config files?

CAPTCHA images are not working and we have confirmed that the passwords are correct with different users in the database.

Comment: this is probably a question suited for the atlassian forums..

Answer (score 0):

Go to confluence administration, section Security Configuration, uncheck the box captcha on login.